# Travis: configuration to run dart tests

Tags: travis-ci, angular-dart

I'm trying to run angulardart tests on Dartium with Travis but it fails with this error:

`Failed to load "test/data_services/app/company/Coordinates_test.dart": Failed to run Dartium: Dartium failed with exit code 1..`

Here is my build script:

```
matrix:
  include:
    - language: dart
      sudo: false
      dart: stable
      dist: trusty
      before_install:
        - cd $TRAVIS_BUILD_DIR/webapp-angular
      install_dartium: true
      script:
        - pub get && pub run test --platform dartium test/


    - language: java
      jdk: oraclejdk8
      sudo: false
      script:
        - mvn clean verify
```

I'm not sure if it's a problem on my part or the dart commands in Travis CI.